# Username from CAS and Roles from another database

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas, jasig

I have CAS 3 Spring 3.2 and Spring Security 3.2 running on tomcat 7 with a MySQL database.

We use the MySQL database with CAS to authenticate users, then we pass attributes after successful, we get those details from a database called say"sso"

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">

    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="select * from user where {0}" />
    <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="username" value="user_name" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="user_name" value="username" />
            <entry key="full_name" value="fullname" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that what we want to do is get the username from those attributes, then go to an application specific database say called "app".

So what we want to do is get the username from CAS after successful authentication, then get its roles from the database.

How can we do that correctly ?

**UPDATE**

Ok now what I have tried so far and I don't really know is that valid or not.

I have implemented `UserDetailsService` and I created a `UserEntityDetails` which extends my `UserEntity` and Implements `UserDetails`, Then I used my `UserDetailsService` to load my custom created class.

Then in my XML I made this

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthProvider" user-service-ref="DBUserServiceDetails" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Is this the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, what you're asking for is the normal usage pattern - the `CasAuthenticationProvider` is configured with a `UserDetailsService` which loads the roles from a local database rather than CAS.

If you take a look at the [CAS sample application configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/cas/sample-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml#L33), you would simply replace the `userService` bean with your own implementation which loaded the user information from your application-specific database.

Comment: ok well then why is the password here ? shouldn't the password be at CAS ?

Comment: It's there just because that's the syntax for the `user-service` namespace which is being used for simplicity here. The `CasAuthentictaionProvider` shouldn't care about the password property of the loaded `UserDetails` object. You might want to read [this part of the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#cas-sequence). Step 14 is where the roles are loaded.

Comment: ok sorry for the late response, please check my updated question

Comment: Your UserDetailsService should be injected into the CasAuthenticationProvider. You shouldn't have both `ref` and `user-service-ref` set in the `authentication-provider` element. Again, please see the sample configuration for reference. It should be pretty much like that apart from the `UserDetailsService` being a separate bean.